# Kafka Consumer not working on local using KafkaJS

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafkajs

I am trying to run a Kafka consumer in local using KafkaJS. It shows that the consumer is running but it's not consuming from a topic in which the producer is actively pushing events to. The consumer used to work a week back but something happened after which it stopped consuming the events. The same setup when run on development env is running properly and even handling the events. Not able to debug what exactly happened.

These are the utiliy functions that I have written

```
const kafka = new Kafka({
  clientId: "integrations-queues",
  brokers: [
    process.env.KAKFA_CONNECTION_URL_1,
    process.env.KAKFA_CONNECTION_URL_2,
  ],
});

const createKafkaConsumer = (groupId: string) => {
  const consumer = kafka.consumer({
    groupId,
  });

  return consumer;
};

const connectAndSubscribeKafkaConsumer = async (
  consumer: Consumer,
  topic: string
) => {
  try {
    await consumer.connect();

    await consumer.subscribe({ topic });
  } catch (error) {
    SentryService.captureException(error);
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

```
(async () => {
  try {
    const consumerGroupName =
      process.env.ENV === "localhost"
        ? "raw-data-consumer-local"
        : process.env.WORKFLOW_RAW_DATA_CONSUMER;

    rawDataConsumer = createKafkaConsumer(consumerGroupName);

    await connectAndSubscribeKafkaConsumer(
      rawDataConsumer,
      process.env.WORKFLOW_EXECUTIONS_PRODUCER_TOPIC
    );

    await rawDataConsumer.run({
      eachMessage: rawEventHandler,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    SentryService.captureException(error);
    console.log(error);
  }
})();
```

I tried searching for the issue if someone had faced a similar issue but wasn't able to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

> used to work a week back

Kafka has default retention period of 7 days. If you have no active producer, then consumer would stop seeing new events. A brand new consumer of course would work because data is fresh.

I suggest using `kafka-consumer-groups` command to check your group-id lag